# Select records from a table that they don't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

How to get table2 records that don't exists in table1 (date filtered)

```
SELECT e.event_id, e.start_time, te.* 
FROM table1 te, table2_tmp e 
WHERE te.book_id = 45
 AND (DATE(STR_TO_DATE(e.start_time,"%Y%m%d%H%i%s")) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND CURRENT_DATE)
```

table1

```
ID      event_id  start_time      book_id
10000   1_1005    20191222135100  45  <-- date Filtered & Doesn't exists in t1
10001   1_1006    20200123139100  45
10002   1_1007    20200124145100  45
10003   1_1010    20200125135100  45
10004   1_1015    20200325135100  46
```

table2

```
ID      bk_event_id  
11111   1_1006   
11112   1_1007         
11113   1_1015
11113   1_1016
```

Expected result

```
ID      event_id  
10000   1_1016
```

Comment: description / heading of tables is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can use outer join: see this example

> > this select all of the teams that do not have players in the PLAYERS table.

```
SELECT t.*,p.* FROM teams t
              LEFT OUTER JOIN players p ON p.team_id = t.team_id
WHERE p.team_id is NULL;
```

Here is a good [example](https://www.linux-tips-and-tricks.de/de/datenbanken/10-sql-joins-einfach-erklaert/)

Comment: This doesn't worked I have tried it before

Comment: To explain this: you need a join to get a result with more rows on one side, on the other side (second table) there will be null-elements if there ist no matching element. You can select those elements by checking on Null ! Try at first an easy example.

Comment: When you join it you say  `p.team_id = t.team_id` by doing this you ignoring the NULL fields. That's why in result you will get the field that actually matches the second table